# How to stop CharField from clearing its data after a new post request?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

How do you stop a char field from clearing data after another post request?

I have a Django template with two forms (`CharField` text area widgets). I have made buttons that upload text files into the respective text boxes.

If I press one of the two buttons, one text box is filled with data but the other is cleared. How do I make both text forms keep their text content even when different post requests are made?

```
if 'uploaded1' in request.FILES:

    upload1 = request.FILES['uploaded1'].read()
    form.initial['textInput1'] = upload1
    args2 = {'uploaded1': upload1, 'form': form, }
    if upload1:
        return render(request, self.template_name, args2)

if 'uploaded2' in request.FILES:
    upload2 = request.FILES['uploaded2'].read()


    form.initial['textInput2'] = upload2

    args2 = {'uploaded2': upload2, 'form': form, }

    if upload2:
        return render(request, self.template_name, args2)
```

Comment: just added, cheers... the 'uploaded1' & 'uploaded2' determine which button was pressed.

Comment: Everything is inside one form @VaibhavVishal, how would I go about that?

Comment: before your if conditions `form.initial['textInput1'] = request.POST['textInput1']`, same for textInput2. After that if conditions will change the initial of one textarea depending on file uploaded.

Comment: thank you that worked, if you make an answer I'll mark yours as solution @VaibhavVishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your if conditions add this:

```
...
form.initial['textInput1'] = request.POST['textInput1']
from.initial['textInput2'] = request.POST['textInput2']
...
```

I think you can avoid all this if you initialize your form Instance like this (not sure, let me know if it works):

```
form = MyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```

Comment: test the other solution too and let me know if that works.